# BLAS dnrm2 on Scipy returns wrong value. Possible wrong flattening

Tags: matrix, cython, blas

I am trying to use Scipy's BLAS functions from Cython and i want to call the dnrm2 for the l2 norm on a 2D typed memoryview.
From the BLAS documentation, the dnrm2 returns the Euclidian norm of a vector. Which is equivalent to the Frobenius Norm for a Matrix. We flatten the matrix and then pass to the function.

```
from scipy.linalg.cython_blas cimport dnrm2

ctypedef np.float32_t dtype_t


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef dtype_t l2_norm(dtype_t[:, ::1] array):
    cdef int m = array.shape[0]
    cdef int n = array.shape[1]
    cdef np.intp_t lda = m
    cdef np.intp_t incx = 1
    cdef dtype_t result
    cdef np.float64_t *data = <np.float64_t*>&array[0, 0]
    result = <dtype_t>dnrm2(&n, data, &incx)
    return result
```

dnrm2 accepts only fp64 numbers so i have to do the type casting with the default datatype.

unfortunately anyway the function returns the wrong result.
Am i flattening the array wrongly here or am i using this completely wrong?
`cdef np.float64_t *data = <np.float64_t*>&array[0, 0]`

For the following matrix

```
array([[0.65411323, 0.73329186, 0.74279535],
       [0.617243  , 0.6950498 , 0.99457264],
       [0.5428702 , 0.34277368, 0.73931944]], dtype=float32)
```

it returns `0.007486129179596901`
while the real value is `2.0807159881759274`

Answer (score 2):

```
    cdef np.float64_t *data = <np.float64_t*>&array[0, 0]
```

**This will not work**. You have a pointer to a 32 bit array. You cast that to a pointer to a 64 bit array. This does not change the underlying data. It just lies about what it points to.

I suspect you want `snrm2` instead. If not then you need as *make a copy* of the underlying array with a different dtype (e.g. [`np.ndarray.astype`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html#numpy-ndarray-astype))